# Изменить цвет формы при checked = true

Tags: delphi

```
unit U3_4;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

TForm1 = class(TForm)
CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
RadioButton1: TRadioButton;
RadioButton2: TRadioButton;
RadioButton3: TRadioButton;
RadioButton4: TRadioButton;
procedure CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton3Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton4Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }

public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RadioButton1.Enabled := True;
  RadioButton2.Enabled := True;
  RadioButton3.Enabled := True;
  RadioButton4.Enabled := True;
  if CheckBox1.Checked = False then
    RadioButton1.Enabled := False;
  if CheckBox1.Checked = False then
    RadioButton2.Enabled := False;
  if CheckBox1.Checked = False then
    RadioButton3.Enabled := False;
  if CheckBox1.Checked = False then
    RadioButton4.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.RadioButton1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = True then
    Form1.Color := clBtnFace;
end;

procedure TForm1.RadioButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = True then
    Form1.Color := clRed;
end;

procedure TForm1.RadioButton3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = True then
    Form1.Color := clYellow;
end;

procedure TForm1.RadioButton4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = True then
    Form1.Color := clGreen;
end;

end.
```

ВОПРОС: Как сделать так, чтобы только при значении checked = true цвет формы менялся. То есть мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при снятии флажка с checkbox1 цвет формы был по умолчанию

Comment: код конечно корявый, можно было оптимизировать, например избавиться от многочисленных присвоений, лишних условий и так далее... В общем надо работать над этим как-то, Вам.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вешаешь на клик на checkbox1 код:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = True then begin
    if RadioButton1.Checked then
      RadioButton1Click(Self);
    if RadioButton2.Checked then
      RadioButton2Click(Self);
    if RadioButton3.Checked then
      RadioButton3Click(Self);
    if RadioButton4.Checked then
      RadioButton4Click(Self);
  end else begin
    Form1.Color := clBtnFace;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Не работает...

Comment: почему не работает, на что дельфи ругается?

Comment: на RadioButton2Click(Self)

Comment: @Luchfan12, если Вы просто скопировали ответ, @hovadur, то возможно из-за того, что у Вас RadioButton1DblClick, а у @hovadur просто RadioButton1Click и ругается скорее всего на это

Comment: -1. не надо такой код писать, даже для примера.

Comment: Я переписал бы этот код по-другому, но какой он у автора, то такой я и предлагаю.